# How to undo a "revert" commit that hasn't been pushed?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am getting a message like the following, which is different from the answer available, as this is for my job I don't want to mess up again.

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   src/components/LayoutSideNavigation/LayoutSideNavigation.js
        deleted:    src/components/LayoutWrapperListingsSideNav/LayoutWrapperListingsSideNav.js
        modified:   src/components/index.js
        deleted:    src/containers/ApprovedListingsPage/ApprovedListingsPage.duck.js
        deleted:    src/containers/ApprovedListingsPage/ApprovedListingsPage.js
        modified:   src/containers/ManageListingsPage/ManageListingsPage.js
        modified:   src/containers/ManageListingsPage/ManageListingsPage.module.css
        modified:   src/containers/ManageListingsPage/__snapshots__/ManageListingsPage.test.js.snap
        deleted:    src/containers/PendingListingsPage/PendingListingsPage.js
        deleted:    src/containers/RemovedListingsPage/RemovedListingsPage.js
        modified:   src/containers/index.js
        modified:   src/containers/pageDataLoadingAPI.js
        modified:   src/containers/reducers.js
        modified:   src/paths.js
        modified:   src/routeConfiguration.js
        modified:   src/translations/en.json

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        package-lock.json
```

Basically, I had to unmerge these changes, for which I did revert after pulling the code from github on master, but it removed all code from my local repo as well. I want to keep the code saved. So I am trying to uncommit, make a branch, save the code on that branch, and then undo from that branch.

Also, how to push these reverted changes? As I don't see any difference on the github repository, and if I create a forced PR, it doesn't include these changes in it (I tried from a branch at that time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should issue the following commands:

```
git stash save
git checkout -b saved-commit
git stash pop
git commit -a -m "Merge commit."
git push -u origin/saved-commit
git checkout master
```

Comment: I am still in the master branch after creating saved-commit branch, as you have written ```git branch saved-commit``` instead of ```git branch -b saved-commit```, is that alright?

Comment: but I have already run till ```git commit -a -m "Merge commit."```, now, what should I do, the same thing?

Comment: You have to go back before retry my code. Issue a git log, copy the hash where you need to go back, then `git reset <COMMIT-HASH>`.